# React button component with switch statement

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi all trying to make a button component that converts to an `anchor` tag when changing a prop. Im using a `switch` statement but nothing changes when I change the prop and the `onClick` is not being handled? Im using NextJS's `Link` component for the `anchor` tag

```
const Button = ({ children }, props) => {
    switch (props.as) {
        case 'link':
            return (
                <Link
                    href={props.link}
                    onClick={props.click}
                    className={styles.hello}>
                    {props.icon && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} />}
                    {children}
                </Link>
            );
        case 'button':
            return (
                <button
                    onClick={props.click}
                    type='button'
                    className={styles.btn}>
                    {props.icon && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} />}
                    {children}
                </button>
            );
        default:
            return (
                <button
                    onClick={props.click}
                    type='button'
                    className={styles.btn}>
                    {props.icon && <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.icon} />}
                    {children}
                </button>
            );
    }
};
```

in my Parent component I'm importing the Button and using it like:

```
    <Button
                            as='link'
                            icon='coffee'
                            click={props.handleAccept}>
                            RSVP
                        </Button>
```

In render it appears a button rather than expected anchor tag. Any ideas please?

Comment: Have you done a `console.log(props.as)` inside the `Button` component to verify that the prop's value is what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const Button = ({ children, ...props }) => {
```

It should be like this, props is not second parameter

Comment: Thanks, that was it.

Answer (score 0):

When declaring the Button component, try moving the props inside the destructed object like this and ... in front of it.

const Button = ({ children, ...props }) => {.......};

Comment: Thank you you are correct, I think @MCcRist came to the same conclusion I appreciate the input.